# Decide if there exist $a$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^2=2b^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Decide if there exist $a$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^2=2b^2$.

$a,b \neq 0$

We have to solve this kinds of problems using the order of a prime function:

$v_p(a) \in \mathbb{Z}$ which tells the exponent of a prime $p$ in the factorization of an integer $a$.

I managed to find that $a$ must be $even$ using 
$$
2b^2|a^2 \longrightarrow v_2(a^2)\geq 1, v_2(a^2)=2v_2(a)
$$
$$
2v_2(a)\geq1 \longrightarrow v_2(a)\geq \frac 1 2 \longrightarrow v_2(a)\geq 1
$$

But don't know what to do next...

Comment: If it is only about existence, then $a=0$ and $b=0$ are sufficient. However, these are the only solution: you'll have $\frac{a}{b}=\sqrt{2}$ but it is an irrational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Compare parity: $\ v_2(a^2) = 2 v_2(a)\,$ is even, but $\,v_2(2b^2) \,=\, 1+2\, v_2(b)\,$ is odd.

Comment: So I conclude this by stating that amount of $2$s in $a$ and $b$ is different right? Thanks!

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Not in $a$ vs. $b$. Rather,  $a^2$ vs $2b^2$, as above.